# Volley library inconsistent correct responses

Tags: android, android-volley

I've been using Volley to do network tasks on my apps. This time, it's very often giving me inconsistent responses. Sometimes error responses, sometimes correct. Here's my code:

```
public void requestGet(final Context context, final String url){
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

And here's the logcat when error happened sometimes:

```
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 0
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 0
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
32646-32646/com.example.apps W/System.err:  ... 1 more
```

Some informations:

1. I've tried to test my urls on PC browsers and they all gave correct responses.
2. When an error happened, it would happen in very short time. So, it seems to me that the retry policy wasn't really the problem.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You have to handle error response properly for volley. Like NoConnection Error, Network Error, Server Error, Parse Error, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, However, the point of my problem is that it's sometimes gave error response, sometimes correct. It's about inconsistency. About not handling error response properly, I think that's a different problem.

Comment: That will happen because of slow net connection, or default retry-policy of volley, or due to error like parameter error(network error).

Comment: I've posted my volley code above, can you please check if its retry policy wasn't right please? I think slow net or network error is also possible. However, I would still confused as I can open the urls on the volley on PC browsers, and it would always show correct responses in relatively short time.

Comment: Try my answer for retry policy.

Comment: I'm sorry, still no luck. Anyway, when an error happened, it would happen in very short time. So, it seems that the retry policy wasn't really the problem.

Comment: Without my retrypolicy code, did you get error in short time? Then Buddy, Wish some one understand your question and solve your problem. I think it's because of slow internet or connecting to server issue. good luck!!!

Comment: I see, I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. And thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: @NitinPatel, do you have any suggestions regarding what server issue exactly? I already changed server where other apps working correctly, but the problem on this app persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Here first parameter is timeout, it should be greater than 0 e.g. 10000(10s).

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that. Still, sometimes error responses, sometimes correct.

Comment: The reason might be the network on your device. Try to increase the timeout duration to longer times. That might solve the issue.

Comment: And set the retry count to 0. In that case it would try only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this retry policy:-

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5*1000,-1,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```